# GridView of photos and zoom on tap of any image

Tags: grid, uicollectionview, gallery, uicollectionviewcell, image-gallery

I wish to create a grid-like photo gallery, where there are 3 photos in each row which has same frame size. When user taps on any photo, it has to zoom as given in the attached image & other photos has to get aligned accordingly.

[image: Screenshot]

I am new to UICollectionView. However I have managed to display 3 cells in a single row as given in the below screenshot.

I have done this similar to the display of UITableview. I have created a new UICollectionviewCell Class in which the frame of a single cell is declared.

**bigBoxIndex** is the **indexpath.row** in which the cell has to be expanded.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (bigBoxIndex == indexPath.row) {

        return CGSizeMake(bigBoxWidth, bigBoxHeight);
    }
    else {
        return CGSizeMake(boxWidth, boxHeight);
    }
}


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DealListCVCell *cell = (DealListCVCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    DealListCVCell *expandedCell = (DealListCVCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:bigBoxIndex inSection:0]];

    if (bigBoxIndex == indexPath.row) {
        bigBoxIndex = -1;
    }
    else {
        bigBoxIndex = indexPath.row;
    }

    if (bigBoxIndex == -1) {

        [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

            for (NSInteger i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITEMS; i++) {

                NSIndexPath *fromIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                NSInteger j = i;

                NSIndexPath *toIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:0];
                [collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath toIndexPath:toIndexPath];

            }
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];

            [UIView beginAnimations:@"Zoom" context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
            [expandedCell.dealImg setFrame:CGRectMake(2.0f, 2.0f, boxWidth-4.0f, boxHeight-4.0f)];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
    else {

            [UIView beginAnimations:@"Zoom" context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
            [cell.dealImg setFrame:CGRectMake(2.0f, 2.0f, (2 * boxWidth)-4.0f, (2 * boxHeight)-4.0f)];
            [UIView commitAnimations];


            [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

            [expandedCell.dealImg setFrame:CGRectMake(2.0f, 2.0f, boxWidth-4.0f, boxHeight-4.0f)];

            for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [[self.entries objectAtIndex:0] count]; i++) {

                NSIndexPath *fromIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
                NSInteger j = i;

                NSIndexPath *toIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:0];
                [collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath toIndexPath:toIndexPath];
            }
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
    }
}
```

[image]

As per my code, when user taps on an image, it gets enlarged as given in the below screenshot.

[image]

How can I manage the layout of a single row?